# Prove that if $e.d \equiv 1 \text{ mod } pq$ then it's impossible to have $e.d \equiv 1 \text{ mod } (p-1)(q-1)$

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic

I am studying RSA cryptosystem and here is the question that came to my mind. Let's pick $p, q$ to be two primes and $n = p * q$. From that we calculate Euler's totient function:

$$
\phi(n) = (p - 1)(q - 1).
$$ Then we chose the public and private key pair as $e, d$ such that:
$$
e * d \equiv 1  \text{ mod } \phi(n).
$$

Now I want to prove that for the same pair $(e, d)$ it no longer holds that:

$$
e * d \equiv 1 \text{ mod } n.
$$

I have tried writing:
$$
e * d = k * \phi(n) + 1\\
e * d = l * n + 1,
$$
for some integer $k$ and $l$.
So it should be that:
$$
k * \phi(n) + 1 = l * n + 1 \\
k * \phi(n) = l * n. \\
$$
So replacing the values of $n = pq$ and $\phi(n) = (p - 1)(q - 1)$ we get:
$$
k * (p - 1) * (q - 1) = l * p * q. 
$$
I sense that there is an impossibility. But can't figure out what it is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the proposition to prove exactly? The proposition in title is incorrect. A counterexample is $e=d=1$. Another with $e$ valid in some mathematical definition of RSA is $p=13$, $q=17$, $e=5$, $d=16973$. These parameters work, in the sense that we can successfully decrypt with $(n,d)$ what was encrypted with $(n,e)$.

Comment: I don't understand what you exactly mean. I think your question can be converted to another representation: There is no isomorphic function $\zeta:Z^*_{\phi(N)}\to Z^*_N$ , s.t. given two group elements $e,d=e^{-1} \in Z^*_{\phi (N)}$, $\zeta(e)\cdot\zeta(d)=1modN$.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I want to prove that for the same pair $(e,d)$ it no longer holds that:

That you are running into difficulties proving it may be due to the fact that it is, as you have laid out, not true.

Consider the values:

$$e = 1 + apq(p-1)(q-1)$$
$$d = 1 + bpq(p-1)(q-1)$$

for arbitrary integers $a, b$.

With these values, it is straight-forward to verify that these both hold:

$$ed = 1 \pmod{(p-1)(q-1)}$$
$$ed = 1 \pmod{pq}$$

Of course, if $a, b > 0$, these are huge values of $d, e$, but there's nothing that says they can't be huge.

On the other hand, if we add in the assumptions that:

- $p-1$ does not have $q$ as a factor
- $q-1$ does not have $p$ as a factor
- $p, q$ are both primes (standard with RSA; let us be explicit about that)
- $e, d > 1$
- $e, d < \phi(n)$

Then both relations cannot hold simultaneously.  I believe that you would find it instructive to show that from what you have; the steps you have written out is already half the work...

---

To show that the first two assumptions are necessary, I found this counterexample if we don't include those assumptions:

$$N = 5671 = 53 \times 107$$
$$E = 615$$
$$D = 959$$

Computation shows that both $E\cdot D = 1 \pmod{N}$ and $E \cdot D = 1 \pmod{\phi(N)}$